# Antlr Lexer exclude a certain pattern

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In Antlr Lexer, How can I achieve parsing a token like this:

A word that contains any non-space letter but not '.{' inside it. Best I can come up with is using a semantics predicate.

```
WORD: WL+   {!getText().contains(".{")};
WL: ~[ \n\r\t];
```

I'm a bit worried to use semantics predicate though cause WORD here will be lexed millions of times I would think to put a semantics predicate will hit the performance.

This is coming from the requirement that I need to parse something like:

```
TOKEN_ONE.{TOKEN_TWO}
```

while TOKEN_ONE can include . and { in its letter.

I'm using Antlr 4.

Comment: I think your question needs more detail. I've made an answer, revised it a few times, and deleted it, all because there are a lot of edge-cases that haven't been addressed. For example, must `foo{}bar` really be a `WORD`? Is it OK to write `foo. {bar}`? etc.

Comment: yeah foo{}bar will be a word, and foo. {bar} as well. The reason to have this kind of thing is not because I want to tokenize them to be word of any sense, they will just be freetext which can take any letter, but .{ will start another kind of token. I will explain more in the main question.

Comment: Depending on how much behavior changes inside `.{}` sections you may want to look at the [lexical modes](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules) feature. That way, when entering `.{`,  you can switch to a set of lexer-rules that no longer recognizes `}` as a valid word-character. (Otherwise `foo.{bar}baz` might be interpreted as `foo`, `.{`, `bar}baz`.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to limit your predicate evaluation to the case immediately following a `.` in the input.

```
WORD
  : ( ~[. \t\r\n]
    | '.' {_input.LA(1)!='{'}?
    )+
  ;
```

Comment: thanks, I will try this out, Looks like is what I want to achieve.

Comment: I had a try with this, but strangely it looks like that once the predicate is evaluated to be false, i.e., an .{ has encountered, the predicate is not evaluated any more! any idea why?

Comment: I have formalized the problem i encountered in the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283151/antlr-lexer-semantic-predicate-on-an-alternative Can you please have a look? thanks a lot.

Answer (score -2):

How about rephrasing your question to the equivalent "A word contains any character except whitespace or dot or left brace-bracket."

Then the lexer rule is just:

```
 WORD:  ~[ \n\r\t.{]*
```