# Antlr lexer semantic predicate on an alternative

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Given the grammar:

```
grammar Test;
words: (WORD|SPACE|DOT)+;
WORD : (
       LD
       |DOT       {_input.LA(1)!='.'}?
       ) +        ;
DOT: '.';
SPACE: ' ';
fragment LD: ~[.\n\r ];
```

with Antlr4 generated Lexer, for an input:

```
test. test.test test..test
```

The token sequence is like:

```
[@0,0:4='test.',<1>,1:0]
[@1,5:5=' ',<3>,1:5]
[@2,6:14='test.test',<1>,1:6]
[@3,15:15=' ',<3>,1:15]
[@4,16:19='test',<1>,1:16]
[@5,20:20='.',<2>,1:20]
[@6,21:25='.test',<1>,1:21]
[@7,26:25='<EOF>',<-1>,1:26]
```

What puzzles why the last piece of text `test..test` is tokenized into `test`  `.` and `.test`, while I was supposed to see `test.` `.test`

What puzzled me more is for input:

```
test..test test. test.test
```

the token sequence is:

```
[@0,0:3='test',<1>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='.',<2>,1:4]
[@2,5:9='.test',<1>,1:5]
[@3,10:10=' ',<3>,1:10]
[@4,11:14='test',<1>,1:11]
[@5,15:15='.',<1>,1:15]
[@6,16:16=' ',<3>,1:16]
[@7,17:20='test',<1>,1:17]
[@8,21:25='.test',<1>,1:21]
[@9,26:25='<EOF>',<-1>,1:26]
```

Here the `test.test` is separated into two tokens while in above it is one.
Is the calling of _input.LA(1) has some side effect to cause this? Can some one explain?

I'm using Antlr4.

Comment: Am I right, that you want to ignore double `DOT` in your `WORD` lexer rule?

Comment: yes. it is actually from my another question: :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224181/antlr-lexer-exclude-a-certain-pattern I formalised the root problem to this question hoping to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is to check the previous `LA(-1)` token if it is unequal `.` and add a leading optional `DOT`.

Resulting grammar is:

```
grammar Test;
words: (WORD|SPACE|DOT)+;
WORD : DOT? (
       LD
       |{_input.LA(-1)!='.'}? DOT       
       ) +        ;
DOT: '.';
SPACE: ' ';
fragment LD: ~[.\n\r ];
```

Have fun and enjoy ANTLR, it is a nice tool.

Comment: hi, can u care to explain it a bit more, like how the predicates are supposed to work in ANTLR and why the grammar in my question doesn't work? Semantic predicates seems a powerful tooland I really want to know what is happening underneath. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please check the API of ANTLR relating to the function you use. You find it under (http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/IntStream.html#LA(int)). There you see that the `-1`is essential to check against the previous Character, because in detail you are looking at a `CharStream` (type of `_input` in lexer (http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/Lexer.html#_input) ). Hope this will help you with your problem.